# Accessing a function within a function inside object literals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have some code as follows -

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('backbutton',this.receivedEvent.backbutton(),false);
                                                    ^-- //not working
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

 receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var originalLocation, partnership;

    function fadeOut(element, direction) {
       ....
    };

    function fadeIn(element, direction) {
        .....
    }

    function formFadeIn(direction) {
        fadeIn($("#dataform"), direction);
    };

    function formFadeOut(direction) {
        fadeOut($("#dataform"), direction);
    };

    function backbutton () {
        var current = $("#home").attr("page-current");
        var prev = $("#home").attr("page-prev");
        if (current == "dataform" && prev == "partnertype") {
            formFadeOut("opposite");
            partnertypeFadeIn("opposite");
            setPage("country", "partnertype")
            $("#selectcountry").attr("disabled", false).val("AF")
        } else if (current == "dataform" && prev == "country") {
            formFadeOut("opposite");
            countryFadeIn("opposite");
        } else if (current == "partnertype" && prev == "country") {
            partnertypeFadeOut("opposite");
            countryFadeIn("opposite");
        } else {
            window.location.reload()
        }
    }
}
};

app.initialize();
```

So I need to bind the event "backbutton" to the `function backbutton()` within `receivedEvent`. `function backbutton()` is invoking local functions within `receivedEvent` such as `formFadeIn()` etc.

I am unable to figure out the exact syntax on binding.

What I've tried -

1. `this.receivedEvent.backbutton` //no response
2. `this.receivedEvent.backbutton()` //no response
3. `this.receivedEvent.bind(this).backbutton` //causes infinite looping on the page
4. exporting the backbutton() function as `return { backbutton : backbutton }` //no response

What do I have to do to access `function backbutton()` from `app.initialize()` without loosing context?

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
var app = {
  initialize: function() {
     document.addEventListener('backbutton',this.myBackButtonFunction, false);
  },

  myBackButtonFunction: function() {
     // Your code
  }
  receivedEvent: function(id) {
     // Can also be invoked from here
    this.myBackButtonFunction(); 
  },

};


app.initialize();
```

Comment: myBackButtonFunction is depended on invoking other functions contained within receivedEvent -- so unfortunately this won't work.